# Stop SMS Receiver

Tags: java, android

I am using SMS Receiver Service which starts from Android Manifest File, using the following code.  The problem is that it will remain working even after the application exits. **How do I stop this service from receiving SMS?**

Start Service CODE:

```
<receiver android:name=".dataAccess.SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: `stopService(new Intent(SMSReceiver.class))` in your activity should do it.

Comment: I doubt it; a BroadcastReceiver isn't even a service.  What you need to do is *unregister* the receiver.  I don't even know if you can do it if the receiver was registered via the manifest.  One possible solution is to use registerReceiver() rather than the manifest, then you'd definitely be able to unregister it programatically.  But now you need to arrange for the code to be called to do the registration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep using a broadcast receiver defined in your manifest, you can still enable / disable it using the package manager.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/manifest-receivers.html)

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SMSReceiver.class);

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick correction before I continue: that's not actually an Android Service, it's a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

The easiest way is to listen for Pause/Resume of your application, and register/unregister the SMS receiver there.  Here's a sample snippet from the Wi-Fi Direct tutorial.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    receiver = new SMSReceiver(...);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```